# Grails 2.5 set datasource on service class not working

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have multiple data sources in my application and I want to be able to switch the datasource on a service class from the default one to a different one (so that it matches my Grails domain). Per the doc it states to use:

```
  static datasource = 'dsName'
```

property on the service class, which I have done. However, the mainTransactionManager is still using my default data source.

I can see in the ChainedTransactionManager that it calls:

```
MultiTransactionStatus mts = new MultiTransactionStatus(transactionManagers.get(0));
```

The 0th index inside of transactionManagers contains my default data source... so how do I **ensure** that it doesn't use the transaction manager that contains the default data source?

Where/when does Grails read the

```
static datasource = '...'
```

property?

Basically I just want to lineup my datasource across my services and my domains.

Answer (score 1):

> Where/when does Grails read the `static datasource = '...'`

That property is read at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/bd7cc10e17d34f20cedce979724f0e3bacd4cdb4/grails-plugin-services/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/services/ServicesGrailsPlugin.groovy#L74

That is invoking the `getDatasource` method at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/bd7cc10e17d34f20cedce979724f0e3bacd4cdb4/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/DefaultGrailsServiceClass.java#L40.

Comment: The answer above address the "where".  "When" is at application startup when the `doWithSpring` closure in `ServicesGrailsPlugin` is invoked.